# AWS Amplify Connecting to GoDaddy - Documentation Unclear - Redirects Too Many Times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, cname

I am trying to connect my Amplify app to a GoDaddy website and the AWS instructions are not clear on how to do this.

Following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/howto-third-party-domains.html) I created a CNAME record to point to my Amplify app.

[image: ocu]

(Image from the documentation)

I have a "master.xxxxxxxx.amplifyapp.com" and a "feature.xxxxxxxx.amplifyapp.com", am I supposed to use one of these or just the "xxxxxxxx.amplifyamp.com"?

It seems from the docs that these records take up to 2 days to update and I do not want to waste 4 days attempting this by trial and error.

### Edit

Following @Rodrigo M's answer I used the 'master.xxxxxxxx.amplifyapp.com' route for the CNAME record but when I go to the page all I see is the error:

> This page isn’t working xxxxx.domain.com redirected you too many times.

And then when I look in the Network tab I see that the page did a bunch of 302 redirects where the name and the initiator were "Index.html".

Does anyone have any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you don't move the DNS servers to Route 53? It makes it so much easier to manage. Only .50c per month.

Comment: Because unfortunately this was already paid for and we didn't know about 53 before. Honestly if things are this hard to just get set up in AWS I am hesitant to become more invested in it. This should be a "Hello World" type setup that no one can give me a straight answer on so far.

Answer (score 3):

Each of the AWS Amplify domains that you reference refer to a branch of your app eg master or feature. Use the full domain name eg `master.xxxxxxxx.amplifyapp.com` as  the target of your CNAME record for the branch you want to expose on your custom domain.

All of the standard DNS propagation warnings say allow 24 to 48 hours but in practice it's usually much much quicker so don't worry about waiting for two days  too much.

I can see your DNS TTL is set for 1 hour. This value is how long the DNS system will cache your DNS records. Which means you can make a change and it would take up to an hour for those records to be updated throughout the internet. You could drop that to 5 minutes or less if you want to do trial and error testing or make quick switches to a different branch.

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy doesn't support ANAME/ALIAS so you can't connect it properly. However you can forward the domain without www

Scroll down to the Forwarding section of the go daddy DNS page and set up a Temporary (302) http forward from `yourdomain.com` to `www.yourdomain.com`

It took about 30min for this to take affect for me.